# Which is more reliable to use object representation or String in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore collection of products (125 and growing). Each product document has about 18 properties (name, price, stock etc). I can get all the documents successfully using:

```
val product = document.toObject(Product::class.java)
```

but I can use:

```
val name = document.getString("name")
```

Which is more recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your actual structure where you have only 125 items, you can use each one you want. If your collection will grow so much as it will contain a very large number of documents, there might be a reasons why you should not use the first approach. Cloud Firestore uses reflection, so in case of very large number of documents, your app might become a little bit slower.

Further more, if you only need to display one or two properties, why to get them all? So if you only really need a subset of the fields, just use the second approach.

So even if we talk about a small data set (maybe it's not your case) but I have seen data that was not formated properly in a way the developer want.

Answer (score 1):

While developing, I often find it more convenient to use the direct accessor methods of the `Document` class to get the fields from a document. During this time I'm still figuring out what precise fields and types each entity has.

If/once all documents have the same fields, and your data model is fairly stable, I'd recommend defining a `Product` class to model the fields from the document in Java/Kotlin code.